# Any method to avoid macros for subfigures captions

Tags: macros

`enter code here`I used macros to customize some captions of figures and equations but EM system can not process it.

```
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}

    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.5.12) 1 MAR 2021 13:52
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**parasitic_motion_analysis.tex
(./Parasitic_motion_analysis.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-05-05> (c:/TeXLive/texmflocal/
tex/latex/aries/elsar
ticle.cls
Document Class: elsarticle 2008/10/09, 1.0.2: Elsevier Science
\@bls=\dimen134
(c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen135
) (c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
) (c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.
(c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen136
\Gin@req@width=\dimen137
) (c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
Package: pifont 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 Pi font support (SPQR)
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for U+pzd on input
line 63.
(c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd
File: upzd.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for U/pzd.
Manuscript File Click here to view linked References
)
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for U+psy on input
line 64.
(c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd
File: upsy.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for U/psy.
))
\c@tnote=\count175
\c@fnote=\count176
\c@cnote=\count177
\c@ead=\count178
\c@author=\count179
\@eadauthor=\toks16
\c@affn=\count180
\absbox=\box45
\keybox=\box46
\Columnwidth=\dimen138
\space@left=\dimen139
\els@boxa=\box47
\els@boxb=\box48
\leftMargin=\dimen140
\@enLab=\toks17
\@sep=\skip49
\@@sep=\skip50
(./Parasitic_motion_analysis.spl) (c:/TeXLive/2020/texmfdist/
tex/latex/natbib/
natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip51
\bibsep=\skip52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count181
)
\splwrite=\write3
\openout3 = `Parasitic_motion_analysis.spl'.
(c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
(c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count182
\Gm@cntv=\count183
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count184
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen141
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen142
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen143
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen144
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen145
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen146
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen147
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen148
\Gm@dimlist=\toks18
)) (c:/TeXLive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/txfonts.sty
Package: txfonts 2008/01/22 v3.2.1
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version
`normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/txr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/txr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/txr/m/n --> OT1/txr/bx/n on input line 22.
\symitalic=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `italic' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/txr/m/it --> OT1/txr/bx/it on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version
`normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/txr/bx/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/txr/bx/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version
`normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/txr/m/it on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/txr/m/it on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/txr/m/it --> OT1/txr/bx/it on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math alphabet \mathsf on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version
`normal'
(Font) OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/txss/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/txss/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/txss/m/n --> OT1/txss/b/n on input line 41.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math alphabet \mathtt on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version
`normal'
(Font) OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/txtt/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/txtt/m/n on input line 50.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/txtt/m/n --> OT1/txtt/b/n on input line 51.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 58.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font) OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/txmi/m/it on input line 58.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font) OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/txmi/m/it on input line 58.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font) OML/txmi/m/it --> OML/txmi/bx/it on input line
59.
\symlettersA=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `lettersA' in version `bold'
(Font) U/txmia/m/it --> U/txmia/bx/it on input line 67.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 77.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font) OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/txsy/m/n on input line 77.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font) OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/txsy/m/n on input line 77.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font) OMS/txsy/m/n --> OMS/txsy/bx/n on input line 78.
\symAMSa=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `AMSa' in version `bold'
(Font) U/txsya/m/n --> U/txsya/bx/n on input line 94.
\symAMSb=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `AMSb' in version `bold'
(Font) U/txsyb/m/n --> U/txsyb/bx/n on input line 103.
\symsymbolsC=\mathgroup8
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `symbolsC' in version `bold'
(Font) U/txsyc/m/n --> U/txsyc/bx/n on input line 113.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line
120.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version
`normal'
(Font) OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/txex/m/n on input line 120.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version
`bold'
(Font) OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/txex/m/n on input line 120.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version
`bold'
(Font) OMX/txex/m/n --> OMX/txex/bx/n on input line 121.
\symlargesymbolsA=\mathgroup9
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `largesymbolsA' in version
`bold'
(Font) U/txexa/m/n --> U/txexa/bx/n on input line 129.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \mathsterling on input line
164.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 591.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \not on input line 1043.
)
! LaTeX Error: File `ecrc.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.7 ^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
2735 strings out of 480681
32117 string characters out of 5908536
266899 words of memory out of 5000000
18590 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
533028 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
38i,0n,34p,238b,86s stack positions out of
5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Anyway to achieve these without macro?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not think that they really mean macros at page 8 in https://www.ariessys.com/wp-content/uploads/EM_PM_LaTeX_Guide.pdf) --- they allow the use of personal `.sty` files, so they do process macros. Why don't you try to prepare a MWE or at least show the error you get from the submission site?

Comment: I see. Except macros, I don't have any special syntax that could affect the build process form my initial submission? Initial submission perfectly compiled.  
What is MWE, Rmano

Comment: An MWE is this: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) but probably it is not possible here. You should post the part of the log where the error is --- otherwise it's impossible to say.

Comment: "32117 string characters out of 5908536
266899 words of memory out of 5000000
18590 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
533028 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
38i,0n,34p,238b,86s stack positions out of
5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced! "

Comment: No, there is no error there. The error should be earlier. This is just the final summary of the compilation run. You should have a `! LaTeX error: ...` or `! TeX error` somewhere in the `log` file or a line starting with `!`

Comment: Th log message is quite long and the space in here has very limited space. I don't how to handle this, here.

Comment: If there is no private content, you can compress the file and attach it to message (I think). But you should be able to find the first error --- this is the important one

Comment: show the error message that will not be more than a few lines starting with`!` ending with `?`

Comment: Included in the "question".

Comment: The error is `! LaTeX Error: File \`ecrc.sty' not found.` --- have you included that file in the submission?

Comment: Exactly! It is included.

Comment: In the same directory of the zip file? Same capitalization? Look at page 8 about the content of the zip file.

Comment: I would check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsYEs.png as a first step. Then check that the file uploaded has exactly the same name as in the `\usepackage{name}`. Otherwise, I am at loss on why it doesn't work.

Comment: I did not use any zip file or folder. I added items one by one . No problem of capitalization as well. The file perfectly compile locally. The problem appear only in the EM system.

Comment: So I'm sorry, no idea...  :-(

Comment: Last check: how do you `load` this `ecrc` file?

Comment: sorry for the late. I almost spent a night and fall a sleep during the morning. Here is how I define the preamble. Thanks

\makeatletter
 
 \makeatother
 
 \documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage{ecrc}
 
 \volume{00}
 

 \firstpage{1}
 
 \journalname{Mechanism and Machine Theory}
 
 \runauth{}
 
 
 \jid{procs}
 %% Give a short journal name for the dummy logo (if needed)
 \jnltitlelogo{Journal}

Comment: That seems correct... :-( sorry I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Thank you Rmano, It looks like EM problem. It is submitted, and staffs said the source file can compile in their end.